# What can be done with following scenario for API Testing Automation?

Tags: rest-assured

I have to test rest api using rest assured API. The API is spring secured(Spring security mechanism is integrated by dev team for authentication). I am able to login using rest assured api and found the JSESSIONID also.

After successful login it send http status 302 means redirection and Cookie is found in Response headers which is used for further request.

Also when I press F12, the same APIs are hit with different HTTP status code. Requested URL :  http://example.com/portal/home/xyz.html. One having status code 302 and other having status code 200.

Please see the image below: Headers information after pressing F12:

[image]

I am not able to redirect to the URL with the following code :

```
 given().redirects().follow(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation about the redirect following under the following link:
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/ReleaseNotes15